# Problema al arrancar proyecto Spring en Visual Studio Code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, vscode

Querria desarrollar mi app de **Spring Boot App** en **Visual Studio Code** ya que es uno de los mas potentes editores actualmente y la comodida de este super con creces **eclipse**.

AL ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
```

Busque sobre el error y encontre que añadiendo esta funcion :

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   // It will set UTC timezone
    System.out.println("Spring boot application running in UTC timezone :"+new Date());   // It will print UTC timezone
}
```

Se deberia de arreglar, quedando asi mi clase **main** de **Spring Boot App**:

```
package com.tienda.tienda;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class DemoApplication {

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   // It will set UTC timezone
            System.out.println("Spring boot application running in UTC timezone :"+new Date());   // It will print UTC timezone
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El lugar donde tienes que especificar la zona horaria es en la cadena de conexión a base de datos, por ejemplo si es una aplicación spring-boot como la tuya, en el `application.properties` (fíjate en el el final de la cadena de conexión):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```